# How to count columns with data from multiple sources in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

I am trying to count columns with values using `WINDOW_MAX` function but I am getting an error saying

> All fields must be aggregate or constant when using fields from
> multiple data sources tableau

Used `WINDOW_MAX` function to count how many cells for each row has values, but getting the attached error. I also tried `countif` function but that also is not working.

This is how my current data tables look like
[data table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SItYf.png)